# How do I separate Codeigniter v4 MVC for admin and public?

Tags: php

I want to separate Codeigniter4 MVC for admin and public. In codeigniter3 this is very easy. But I am unable to do that in Codeigniter v4. I want to use system directory for both MVC. Can anyone help me?

**Example for public**

*http:://abc.com*

**Example for admin**

*http:://abc.com/admin*

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an **admin** folder inside the public folder. Copy All files and folders from public folder to the **admin** folder

[image]

2. Edit the **admin/index.php** file. Add extra **[../]** in **$pathsPath** value

[image]

3. Create a new **admin** folder in **App** folder. Copy all files and folders from **App** folder to **admin** folder

[image]

4. Edit **adnin/Config/Paths.php**. Add extra **[../]** in every variables except **$viewDirectory** veriable.

[image]

This changes will make separate the admin and public MVC from each other. But the System folder will be the same.

Comment: don't add extra **" ../ '** in $appDiectory